# How do I find the string after a regexp on a single line of text?

Tags: bash, text-processing, solaris, json

I have a text file containing a very long line of JSON data and I need to extract the value of some field.  I realize the easiest way to do this would be to use `jq` or `grep -o`; however, I am on a company machine, so I cannot install `jq`, and we are using a version of Solaris where `grep` does not have the `-o` option. Currently I am using the command:

```
cat json.file   |
    tr "," "\n" |
    awk '/customfield_10701/ { print $0 }' |
    tr '"' "\n" |
    awk 'NR==4'
```

The above works fine, but I can't help but feel that it is overly complicated and there should be a more elegant solution.

Example of `json.file`:

```
... jshdgfjhsdgfjh,"customfield_10701":"Some Branch","customfield_10702ksghdkfsdkfjkj ...
```

With my current command I get:

```
Some Branch
```

(which is what I want).

Comment: You got what you want, so why did you raise the question?

Comment: Because I can't help but think that my approach will have a significantly longer run time then if there is a single command that can accomplish this. So I'm trying to find out if anyone knows of a simplified version of my solution or if I'm being redundant in my command.

Comment: If you must use bash, lose the `cat` for starts? Parsing JSON with bash tools may not always work the same way every time. You may want to consider using languages that can parse JSON or `jsawk`: https://github.com/micha/jsawk

Comment: 100% `cut`, verrrry _fragile_:  `cut -d'"' -f 4 input.json`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure there are no `"` characters in the data you're looking for and if there's only one line containing a "customfield_10701" entry in the file,
then

```
sed -n 's/.*"customfield_10701":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p'
```

e.g.,

```
$ cat x
... jshdgfjhsdgfjh,"customfield_10701":"Some Branch","customfield_10702ksghdkfsdkfjkj ...
$ sed -n 's/.*"customfield_10701":"\([^"]*\)".*/\1/p' x
Some Branch
```

Comment: Of course this also assumes that there is no field with a *value* of "customfield_10701".

Comment: @G-Man it shouldn't because a value would be followed by a , whereas this regex uses a : as the field:value separator.

Comment: Oh, good point; I typed before I thought.

Comment: Thanks Stephen! I am receiving JSON as a response from a server, which gives the data with no newline character at the end so this solution doesn't work properly as is, but there is an easy solution. So for anyone who is in a similar situation you can pipe the data through '{ cat ; echo ; }' before piping through 'sed' which will append a newline character to the data and everything should work properly.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `tr` to transform commas into newlines.  And then back again.  You can tell `awk` to use a comma as the Input Record Separator (`RS`).

```
awk -F':' -v RS=',' '/customfield_10701/ { gsub(/"/,"",$2); print $2 }' json.file
```

`gsub()` is used to remove the double-quotes `"` (if any) from field 2.

If required, you can also use `gsub()` to remove leading and trailing spaces and tabs, too:

```
awk -F':' -v RS=',' '/customfield_10701/ {
    gsub(/"|^[[:blank:]]+|[[:blank:]]+$/,"",$2);
    print $2
}' json.file
```

Note that the Output Record Separator (`ORS`) is not automatically changed when RS is changed, it stays at the default (a newline) unless you set it (e.g. with `-v ORS=','`).

Answer (score 0):

The following test works for me using **bash 3 builtin regex engine** and does not require external programs:

```
json='"jshdgfjhsdgfjh,"customfield_10701":"Some Branch","customfield_10702ksghdkfsdkfjkj"'

regex_hint=customfield_10701

[[ $json =~ $regex_hint\":\"(.+)\", ]] && printf '%s\n' "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
```

Prints: **Some Branch**

The regex between '( )' is the "capture group 1", which is saved in "${BASH_REMATCH[1](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html)}"

Note the bash builtin supports [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x17129.html) instead of the more well known [Perl Compatible Regular Expressions](http://www.pcre.org/)